# How to set state of the response to an api call for a complex object to react context in order to not have to make api call again?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-context

I'm working on a  react native typescript project.

**How do I set my context object to the data I receive as a response from an api call?**

I don't want to have to make the API call every time I load the component?
So I want to check the context if it's there , don't make the call.

I see a lot of examples , but none seem to set the state without a function. I just want to be set the context to a new context object. Even if state never changes.

Just set context to a new context then when the component loads again, don't make the API call because the context is already set.

Looking for a hook based example or class based example, preferably hooks.

The documentation either shows just how to pass the context or just how to set the state with a function. I want to simply set the context to be whatever I originally requested for.

The object itself is a Location[] with strings such as name, address, city , state , zip, phone etc so there may be multiple Locations.

Comment: Should the data start as `undefined` (and all code that needs the response should check to make sure it exists before using it), or do you have example/template data that can be used in your program in place of the response before it loads or fails to load? The answer to this question will drive the types in the answer you receive.

Comment: I believe it would be okay if it started as undefined. I just won't load the component or child components if there is no data. The object is a Location[] with a bunch of strings inside of it like address , name , zip , city .

Comment: I saw that you updated your comment with more information only after I had already completed the answer I posted. (Just modify the example data type with the array type in your program.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in React DOM (so that it can work as a demo in the Stack Overflow snippet below). I'm fairly confident that you can adapt it to React Native. I've included comments, and can explain further if anything is not clear.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExLIG4AoUSWOAb2bjlqQIoArgBt4KAM6IqMADQ84aSihhIAwhAB2qgB5yFQieq279vQ0gCiBAkgzzzRgMowVSB3BgBPMEmnoYSxEkECRtD29ffwwAOQh+eQBfQmJSChkmZmYAemy4ABUACz9IvwgCPhUUFJI4LwghKDgAQQAFAElmUrhLHRRwYMwquABeLgUtJAAuOAkYKGBNAHMWXhgAdwgZzSEQACMkKBZElhy8gAkkEV8mgiFNDGAtQmhPYtnQUTdaFo7Ce8ezwOIgg62YdweMCemj4VxQXjgAAoQBJtrsDlAAJQzVqpYBGAA8ADcIMBaAA+ca8SgwRowzRIdZwXEkfFIRGUCQQEREvwjSlGGD5UBIBowDlILk89xwFGYzHHLK5FofEBfVQ-XlQCTQuDlN5+CGAmEWH4wCCEJAwNCFA2VVw1Uj1Rq-TqSLwPf6Q3W2a2FIYOxHY5l4wm9fpgQZVSncXgodYoYDwfgieGIgCMAFYAAzZhVwZVFPw6tWpjWuuD4uAANUsCAAmrMQUzALwbgFA9pEWO4iF5NGDvfggCCYhQ0ukh1lGAB0nO5vMRnEmMzIxREILgmygIloZFknk2MwALAAmRIK5iJJV5dqaJPAFAiYAALxK7zQJiQemY780czgAZQDRtE-eAxiUVBVCA0wCXDAYkAAuAAB84HufgCEWJAKURVCBAw2hzzOFU0EMc1SEKCAIAAa17FCdWWO1aGGWhgEoDARC8cEAShZ4LAQoMZlgyN4OGZCcPQhkfljOAxygE0jCgkDEQAhS9HPS9OO9Z5lI-PQWSJMlDiRTgbWAbdKE0RIZk4RRClM2hzIAfhmZAAjifg4DPZyZCCEIwngKTlRcaBXz8RiHUWWZXFUPdFjvB9nz8SQUM0NC8KRAArEi4EfSjEr2CBeRHXgfz-ABtMKUD3QUAIAXVGWikBcNwYL6OCENElLcIk8lsM68TMIIxwrBsOxxSDUYYwUOMJA9NAvWNFCwDCvxxqk3heGVbBNHYy0-TgFAUsW5bIrcSsKiTPgIElTQyHgT98XgLwrSm9bgAqRFSn1CrRhGMYyDEvCyExKl1tB6qqkReNE3gX0bQAoNz1B3hL1B9TQaEJa3CDVYPL3cqqiqq1asRgs8gAPQpymqephRNu2hEoHuOABFsDAzpO1QbIOpZJSnWm8kRIsOeLK1VCaKtFjQEQhH4H4CFeT9CmEOZgF5BkJAkDxlT2IR4BctmliEFAoAO1RJTeFRK3gdZTJ7BktS55Y-AM7Qky8KcR1HK1x0RF6CW04C9CnPSDKaIkHyEJARk4CrEnJF7eGM2yzLCFH1oJbIA9MYPiH0-goHj3g1KyI1uJhZowDAJFg31wJglCbQQZK5NhjGXiIcG6TvdkpE-eYolIq8YJo84eXtAAMX6UyvGXCQDokagjAWAgyESOOsiRuACUKdNyQAVTopY7RU+A2naDOd-jhOt-7wvN63sBKDv++t-ffhn5frhvocuAACknGwDEKccwFjLDel4Bcsc9w7DXHuY8wMZgAANOAAB0YRwAAEQVQwTMAGEk0GJEQWnF+Gc35IA-qDDOj9yHXwzrfDe6dsj0KLoqDSC0K5gAQBReA-Foh118o3KSMkYS+0oVnECId84UK3hwgsH8M7iN0rnUOd9i7MFrjgXAM4wj50RASDhXCIDwGyOSPc9BiINxgFOHm-DLEACEvDtFoIiCg3CgbniAA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.6/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {
//   default as React,
//   createContext,
//   useContext,
//   useEffect,
//   useState,
//   type ReactElement,
//   type ReactNode,
// } from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the above import statments
const {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} = React;

// The type of data from your API
type ExampleData = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
};

// Helper function for the simulated API function below
function delay (ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// A simulated version of the function used to fetch the data from your API
async function fetchData (): Promise<ExampleData> {
  await delay(1500); // The simulated API is VERY slow  (useful for the demo)
  return Promise.resolve({one: 'hello world', two: 42});
}

// Initialize the context
const DataContext = createContext<ExampleData | undefined>(undefined);

// A custom hook for using the data directly
function useData (): ExampleData | undefined {
  return useContext(DataContext);
}

function DataContextProvider ({children}: { children?: ReactNode }): ReactElement {
  // Store the data in state, initialize as undefined (just like above)
  const [data, setData] = useState<ExampleData | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function update () {
      // Only fetch and update state if it doesn't exist yet
      if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
        setData(await fetchData());
      }
    }

    update();
  }, [data, setData]);
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // Only run effect if state changes.
  // (The state setter is included for exhaustiveness,
  // but React guarantees that it will never change identity.)

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App (): ReactElement {
  const data = useData();

  return (
    <div style={{fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}}>

      <h1>Using the Context API</h1>

      <div>
        <pre>
          <code>
            {data ? JSON.stringify({data}, null, 2) : `{\n  "data": undefined\n}`}
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

function AppRoot (): ReactElement {
  return (
    <DataContextProvider>
      <App />
    </DataContextProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppRoot />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll give this a shot. I'm using react native so it might be a little different but probably not much.

Comment: @BeforeTheEmpire All of the React code is identical. Only the rendered views used in the demo are related to React DOM.